# Hide motd banner in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

How do i completely disable ubuntu 16.04 lts motd banner that displays package update and dist upgrade available information
for. eg.

```
475 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

I have moved these 3 files `90-updates-available, 91-release-upgrade, 98-reboot-required`and those messages stopped showing up , i want to make sure if this is correct way

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `dpkg-reconfigure landscape-common` and the files in `/etc/update-motd.d`.

Comment: :) when i run dpkg-reconfigure landscape-common i get package not installed message. and yes i have looked into /etc/update-motd.d/.. and moved those 3 to somewhere else. i guess that will do the job

Comment: A bit of a ugly hack would be `chmod 0600 /etc/update-motd.d`.